# Sql query returning duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Please find the query below:

```
SELECT a.reco_index_content_code,a.reco_index_content_name, a.reco_index_user_action_download_file, 
        CASE WHEN b.refdata_profession_passion_code LIKE '%-%'
                 THEN 'passion'
                 ELSE 'profession' 
             END AS passion_or_profession
FROM tbl_reco_index_contents a 
INNER JOIN tbl_reference_databases b
ON a.reco_index_content_code = b.refdata_content_code
WHERE a.reco_index_user_action_installed = 1 and a.user_profile_number =  1
```

The query returns certain rows repeated. If the query is not self explanatory, I will be more than obliged to revert with further details.

Any help is much appreciated

**Result of query**

```
AAY_AAYAB_FTD00028  PGA TOUR            /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/PGA TOUR.apk profession
AAB_AABAE_FTD00071  PD Central          /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Parkinson's Central.apk   passion
AAB_AABAE_FTD00071  PD Central          /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Parkinson's Central.apk  passion
AAB_AABAE_FTD00072  com.diablo.psychiatry   /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Psychiatry-Neurology Pro.apk passion
AAB_AABAE_FTD00072  com.diablo.psychiatry   /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Psychiatry-Neurology Pro.apk passion
AAB_AABAA_FTD00074  Glasgow                 /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Glasgow Coma Scale Free.apk  passion
AAB_AABAA_FTD00073  FOUR Score          /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/FOUR score.apk   passion
AAB_AABAA_FTD00075  Qx Calculate             /mnt/sdcard/googleCheckout/Calculate by QxMD.apk   passion
```

Comment: can you show the result of your query?

Comment: modified my question with result

Comment: This will happen if there are multiple rows in the joining table with matching `refdata_content_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the results you showed, a simple `DISTINCT` will remove the duplicates since all values in the columns are the same in both rows,

```
SELECT DISTINCT .....
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. I will accept the answer after a bit more testing. Thanks again.